# Flex movable view issue with textinput

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am trying to make a view (containing a textinput) movable when the user drags the view anywhere but the textinput. Here is the code:

```
view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleDown);
view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleUp);`
```

and the handlers:

```
  private function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
     //move the view if anything else than input text and action is selected
     if (!event.target.hasOwnProperty("text") && !DragManager.isDragging) {
        this.startDrag();
     }
  }
  private function handleUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
     this.stopDrag();
  }
```

The problem is that if I try to mark part of the text in the textInput with the mouse I am moving the view again. How I can fix this?

P.S. I also tried to start dragging if I'm not in the textInput hit area:

```
   var point:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
   if (!view.textInput.hitTestPoint(point.x, point.y))) {
        this.startDrag();
   }
```

but it doesn't work too (says I'm out of the text input even if I am in it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a check for event.parent.hasOwnProperty("text") fixed the problem because when I was clicking on the text the target was the text itself, but not the text input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this condition to the handleDown function:

Here is a working sample:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleDown);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
//move the view if anything else than input text and action is selected
  if (stage.focus != mc.textInput) {
    this.startDrag();
  }
}

function mouseUp(e:Event):void
{
    mc.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The view still gets moved when I try to select part of the text with the mouse. For some reason it works only when I first press somewhere in the textInput without text.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
     //move the view if anything else than input text and action is selected
     if (!event.currentTarget.hasOwnProperty("text") && !DragManager.isDragging) {
        this.startDrag();
     }
  }
  private function handleUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
     this.stopDrag();
  }
```

Comment: Do clarify, please. As I see it you only changed target to currentTarget. The difference between them is that the target is the one that dispatched the event that you are currently handling. So the currentTarget changes, the target doesn't and I don't see how this change will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not understand the problem properly.

this may help , If you can afford an extra variable "isDraggable" .

```
private var isDraggable:Boolean = true;  // You can make any component non-draggable  

    view.textInput.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleTIDown);
    view.textInput.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleTIOut);
    view.textInput.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleTIOut);        


    view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleDown);
    view.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleUp);




 private function handleTIDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
      isDraggable = false;

  }
  private function handleTIOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
     isDraggable = true;
  }


 private function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
     //move the view if anything else than input text and action is selected
     if (isDraggable && !event.target.hasOwnProperty("text") && !DragManager.isDragging) {
        this.startDrag();
     }
  }
  private function handleUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
     this.stopDrag();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this wasn't quite the thing I needed - check out the selected answer below :)